# MAX in Select statement not returning the highest value?

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have a question regarding the max-statement in a select -

Without the MAX-statemen i have this select:

```
SELECT stockID, DATE, close, symbol
  FROM ta_stockprice JOIN ta_stock ON ta_stock.id = ta_stockprice.stockID
WHERE stockid = 8648
ORDER BY close
```

[image]

At the end i only want to have the max row for the close-column so i tried:

[image]

Why i didn´t get date = "2021-07-02" as output?

(i saw that i allways get "2021-07-01" as output - no matter if i use MAX / MIN / AVG...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `MAX()` turns the query into an aggregation query.  With no `GROUP BY`, it returns one row.  But the query is syntactically incorrect, because it mixes aggregated and unaggregated columns.

*Once upon a time, MySQL allowed such syntax in violation of the SQL Standard but returned values from arbitrary rows for the unaggreged columns.*

Use `ORDER BY` to do what you want:

```
SELECT stockID, DATE, close, symbol
FROM ta_stockprice JOIN ta_stock ON ta_stock.id = ta_stockprice.stockID
WHERE stockid = 8648
ORDER BY close DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: One additional question -

What can i do when i don´t have the WHERE-statement and want the max(close) row for every stockID - how can i do this (and not for only one specific)?

Normaly i would use the GROUP BY - but his doesn´t work here...

Comment: You would use a window function such as `row_number()` or a correlated subquery.

Comment: I think with that now it worked as expected -  

```
SELECT id, symbol, DATE, close
FROM 
 (SELECT 
  ta_stock.id,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
   PARTITION BY ta_stock.id
   ORDER BY close ASC) row_num,
  symbol,
  DATE,
  close
 FROM ta_stockprice INNER JOIN ta_stock ON ta_stockprice.stockID = ta_stock.id
 ) tmp
WHERE row_num = 1
ORDER BY DATE DESC
```

The only thing i also want to achieve is to filter out that stocks which have less then 50 entries in the ta_stockprice table

But i don´t know why to set this WHERE (or HAVING?) statement...?